# JBoss 6 - War deployment

Tags: jboss6.x

everybody.
I am working in the following context:

- Eclipse Helios Service Release 2
- Jboss 6
- JDK 6

I have observed that JBoss deploys the "*war*" file in a temporal directory called "*temp*" (`C:\JBOSS_6\jboss-6.0.0.Final\server\default\tmp`). Every time JBoss is reset, the location of the deployment changes (within the "*temp*" directory). As a result the application cannot find a text file for being read.

When the application try to access the file the following error is showed:

> "C:\JBOSS_6\jboss-6.0.0.Final\server\default\deploy\ScadaJ2eeWeb.war\WEB-INF\classes\es\indra\transporte\central\j2ee\core\resources\config_0000_ESTACION.properties (El sistema no puede encontrar la ruta especificada)"

I have cheked that the file text is included in the war file (uncompressing it as a zip file).

Is there any way to configure JBOSS (or the way to generate the war file with Eclipse) so that the JBoss deploys the war file always in the same directory (in this case in the path "`C:\JBOSS_6\jboss-6.0.0.Final\server\default\deploy\ScadaJ2eeWeb.war\`")?

Thank you very much in advance.

I am using absolute path to read the file.
I need to read this file to generate another. This last one is the same as the first one but one line.
I do the following sequence of sentence:

```
private static final String NAME_FILE_PROP_STAT = "config_0000_ESTACION.properties";
ClassLoader classLoader = BackingUploadMonitoringMaps.class.getClassLoader();
urlResource = classLoader.getResource("es/indra/transporte/central/j2ee/core/resources/" + NAME_FILE_PROP_STAT);
File originalFile = new File(urlResource.getFile());
// I use this class to read the file and generate the other one (changing a certain line) 
Scanner scan = new Scanner(originalFile);
```

When this last sentence is invoked I get the error I mentioned before

```
"C:\JBOSS_6\jboss-6.0.0.Final\server\default\deploy\ScadaJ2eeWeb.war\WEB-INF\classes\es\indra\tran
```

sporte\central\j2ee\core\resources\config_0000_ESTACION.properties (El sistema no puede encontrar la ruta especificada)"

Comment: Are you using relative paths or are you using absolute paths to read that file?

Comment: @Narciso Is that (properties) file supposed to be read-only or not?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to answer to your questions through stackoverflow. I have edited the question and added more information.

Comment: @Narciso you just did (in your comment above, that's the proper way). So, you'll need to write to it, or just read-only access?

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation. I only need to read the file and I have just test a way to do it. I have to access the file in the following way:

Comment: ClassLoader classLoader = MyClass.class.getClassLoader();           InputStream inOriginalFile = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("es/indra/transporte/central/j2ee/core/resources/fileText.txt");   BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inOriginalFile));                                                   String linea = null;                                               while ((linea = br.readLine()) != null) {...

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to know where the WAR gets unpacked to. Simply use

```
InputStream stream = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("...");
```

and read the file from the stream. `java.util.Scanner` can also take stream as input so no need to change anything else.